# Lambda Expression Sql to C# DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

I have the following query in sql database:

```
SELECT a.GroupCode, a.GroupDate 
FROM TableP 
WHERE YEAR(a.GroupDate) = '2023' 
AND a.GroupCode LIKE '0100%';
```

How can I change it into Lambda Expression? What I did is like below:

```
List<TableP> list = await _context.TablePs
            .Where(x => x.GroupCode.StartsWith(request.GroupCode) && x.GroupDate == request.GroupDate)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

So from the lambda above, I want to change `x.GroupDate` like `YEAR(a.GroupDate)`. Then I will create a parameter as a `string`.

Advice please.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't have much experience with LINQ-to-SQL, but perhaps check for a range between two `DateTime` values that covers the entire year (e.g. >= 2023/01/01 00:00:00 and < 2024/01/01 00:00:00) would work here?

Comment: `x.GroupDate.Year` ? if the `GroupDate` is a proper `DateTime` you can do it that way. it will be translated properly to `YEAR(GroupDate)`, linq can do that much at least.

Comment: also, [`DateTime.Year`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.year?view=net-7.0) is an `integer` do make sure your parameter is in correct type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if DataType GroupDate is DateTime ,You can use g.GroupDate.Year and linq translate  to DATEPART(year, [p].[GroupDate])

Example

```
var _result = context.TablePs
.Where(d => x.GroupCode.StartsWith(request.GroupCode) 
           && d.GroupDate.Year == request.GroupDate.Year).ToList();
```

i qet my query with profiler

```
SELECT *
FROM [Persons] AS [p]
WHERE ([p].[GroupCode] LIKE N'dd%') AND DATEPART(year, [p].[GroupCode]) = 2023
```

Comment: Yes, based on my question. This answers is what I need. Cheers, Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it will go through translation to SQL, but you can try this:

```
Where(x => x.GroupCode.StartsWith(request.GroupCode) 
&& x.GroupDate.Year == request.GroupDate.Year)
```

Please note, however, that this makes your SQL date condition not [sargable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean) (meaning your database can't use any indexes on the GroupDate column if you have any) - so a better solution usually would be to use a range - so in SQL instead of
`WHERE YEAR(a.GroupDate) = 2023` you'll use something like
`WHERE a.GroupDate >= '01012023' AND a.GroupDate < '01012024'`.

While this *might* have an effect on performance (assuming you have an index that is relevant to the query and the table is big enough to benefit from using that index) - it does make a much more cumbersome code writing, especially if you're writing linq and not directly SQL - so I wouldn't rush to write it like that unless you encounter a performance problem.
A linq expression that should translate to something like that might be something along these lines (written directly here without testing first)

```
Where(x => x.GroupCode.StartsWith(request.GroupCode) 
   && x.GroupDate >= new DateTime(request.GroupDate.Year, 1, 1) 
   && x.GroupDate < new DateTime(request.GroupDate.Year + 1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: If you create `DbFunctions` you could use `DATETRUNC` on SQL2022 or Azure, which is sargeable.

Comment: @Charlieface I didn't see any indication in official documentation claiming that DateTrunc is sargable, nor did I see it in official documentation of the DbFunctions class....

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2022/10/t-sql-queries/date-bucket-datetrunc-improve-time-based-grouping I think it's in the RC1 release notes if you can find them, and you can clearly see this in the query plan https://dbfiddle.uk/L02pMFkb `DbFunctions` docs wouldn't say that kind of thing, it's just a way of making the function call via EF into SQL. Any case what I meant to say was if you create your own custom `DbFunctions` to make that call

Comment: Your explanation is great. I'll bookmarked as a reference for next requirement. Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `view` in your database, where you can include the `YEAR(GroupDate) as YGroupDate` computation as a field in the `select` clause. Linking that view to your ORM and writing lambda for it would allow you to search for your your records via `YGroupDate`.